# Is there a way to bind an IP in a Docker-Compose Container to a custom URL?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ip

I am running a SnipeIT-instance via Docker-Compose in Terraform using a `.yml`. Since its hosted  via AWS  the  IP address may change from time to time.
Is it possible to set a custom URL that connects to my SnipeIT-Instance what ever the IP atm is.
For example the url: http://SnipeIT-asset.de can be used to connect to my instance what ever the IP might be at the moment.

```
version: '3'

services:

  snipe-mysql:
    container_name: snipe-mysql-t
    image: mysql:5.6
    env_file:
      - /root/example
    volumes:
      - /opt/persistent/mysql/:/var/lib/mysql


  snipe-it:
    image: snipe/snipe-it
    env_file:
      - /root/example
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - snipe-mysql
```

Comment: In an AWS context, I'd put a load balancer in front of your instance, and then set up a Route 53 DNS name pointing at the load balancer.  Nothing you can do at the Docker layer or in your application source code would be able to create the DNS name, though.